# Transform JSON without property names

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, datagrid, devexpress

I have a JSON feed for reports from a REST API that looks something like:

```
{
"columns": [
  {
    "name": "DateAdded"
  },
  {
    "name": "SupportType"
  }
  ...
],
"records": [
  [
    "2016-07-05",
    "Uncategorised"
  ],
  [
    "2016-07-05",
    "Uncategorised"
  ],
  ...
]
}
```

The idea is to achieve a huge saving on the size of the JSON payloads for large reports by only sending the column names once, and then just arrays of values for each row.

However most grids, especially my current candidate, the DevExpress [dxDataGrid](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/?version=16_1), seem to only be happy with more 'correct' JSON, i.e. with redundant property names in each row.

Now I am looking for a very efficient way of transforming the incoming JSON to include property names. My first idea is simply to iterate each row, or value array, by index, and use that index to look up the column/property name in the columns array, and push a proper JS row object with name/value pairs to a new data array for the grid. However, I feel there may just be some more efficient way of transforming the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over each row to transform it into the required format.
There is no way around it if you don't want to deliver the data already in the correct format.

```js
var data = {
  "columns": [
    { "name": "DateAdded" },
    { "name": "SupportType" }
  ],
  "records": [
    [ "2016-07-05", "Uncategorised" ],
    [ "2016-08-06", "Categorised" ]
  ]
};

var transformedData = data.records.map(function(rec, idx) {
  return rec.reduce(function(result, value, idx) {
    result[data.columns[idx].name] = value;
    return result;
  }, {});
});

console.log(transformedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a more straigt forward approach without moving an object through the mechanism of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), because it is not necessary while only one object is to assign and to return.

This works inside with an object, and successive assignment of properties with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and returns the just generated object with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a new array.

```js
var data = { "columns": [{ "name": "DateAdded" }, { "name": "SupportType" }], "records": [["2016-07-05", "Uncategorised1"], ["2016-08-06", "Categorised2"], ["2016-07-05", "Uncategorised3"], ["2016-08-06", "Categorised4"]] },
    transformedData = data.records.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
            o[data.columns[i].name] = b;
        });
        return o;
    });

console.log(transformedData);
```